# optional argument with at least one required parameter

Tags: python, argparse

I want my program to have an optional argument, but when that option is given, the option needs to have at least one parameter. So the help line should be like this:

```
myprog [file] [-a] [-b] [--optionalArgument neededParameter [optionalParameter ...]]
```

How can i archive that with argparse?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--optional', nargs='+', metavar=('neededParameter', 'optionalParameter'))
```

This will require one or more parameters for `--optional`, and the usage message will be printed as:

```
usage: args.py [-h] [-a] [--optional neededParameter [optionalParameter ...]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i knew that, but that's not the solution i want.

Comment: @topic2k what would you like differently from this?

Comment: I want different names for the first arg from --optional and the following args.

Comment: @topic2k I see. That's possible. See my updated post.